# Achartengine barchart not getting displayed on more data

Tags: android, achartengine

I have two problems with Achartengine barchart. My layout is table for data on left and chart on right (as per layout below):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="horizontal">
  <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tblData"></TableLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/layoutChart" />
</LinearLayout>
```

first table layout is for datatable and second linearlayout is for chart. If i put them in a vertical layout, or put table after chart(in this case table will disappear) then either chart or data will not be displayed.

If data becomes large, eventually chart should also grow on right on X axis, but barchart stops displaying and disappears.
Second problem, I am not able to display chart on top and table below it. Changin orientation to vertical makes either chart visible or the table.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Can someone look into this please

Comment: try this for table with vertical orientation  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
.

Comment: Tried but did not work. The problem is with chart.. if chart has less space to get displayed it disappears